# Why is default view width is 100% in react-native? and why there is no default width when using alignItems?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I don't have problem layouting in react-native right now, just want to know the reason of the default width concept

This script below is almost the same

```
<View
   style = {{
      flex: 1
   }}
>
   //The view below has default width "100%"
   <View
      style = {{
          backgroundColor: "red",
          height: 60
      }}
   />
</View>
```

```
<View
   style = {{
      alignItems: "flex-start", //Same render from left, using alignItems makes inside content having no default width 
      flex: 1
   }}
>
   //The view below has no width
   <View
      style = {{
          backgroundColor: "red",
          height: 60
      }}
   />
</View>
```

Should it have the same width behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View` as analogy if `div` in html

- It's `display=block` by default
- `display=block` is `width=100%` by default
- When you use `alignItems`, it's not `display=block` anymore, it's `display=flex`, hence width is not 100%
- To make `width=100%` with `alignItems`, you have to use `alignItems='stretch'`. Or give `flex=1` to child

Although `View` doesn't have `display=block` property, it's just default behavior

So problem is not in react-native, problem is in your understandings of flexbox